# ManyToMany relation Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Modelling my SpringBoot application, using Hibernate and PostgreSQL as database.
Need help to properly establish relation ManyToMany.
Class News:

```
@Entity(name = "news")
public class News implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private String text;
    private String author;
    private Set<HashTag> hashTags = new HashSet<HashTag>(0);
    private byte[] image;

    public News() {
    }

    public News(Date date, String text, String author, Set<HashTag> hashTags, byte[] image) {
        this.date = date;
        this.text = text;
        this.author = author;
        this.hashTags = hashTags;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "news_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "news_hashTag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "news_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hashtag_id"))
    public Set<HashTag> getHashTags() {
        return hashTags;
    }

    public void setHashTags(Set<HashTag> hashTags) {
        this.hashTags = hashTags;
    }

    @Lob
    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

And class HashTag:

```
@Entity(name = "hashTag")
public class HashTag implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Set<News> news = new HashSet<News>(0);

    public HashTag() {
    }

    public HashTag(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "hashtag_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hashTags")
    public Set<News> getNews() {
        return news;
    }

    public void setNews(Set<News> news) {
        this.news = news;
    }
```

When I try save news like this:

```
Set<HashTag> hashTags = new HashSet<>();
hashTags.add(new HashTag("HashTag 1");
hashTags.add(new HashTag("HashTag 2");

News news = new News();
news.text = "Some text";
news.author = "Some author";
news.date = new Date();
news.hashTags = hashTags;

newsService.save(news);
```

I'm getting error:

> ERROR: null value in column "news_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: You could try `hashTags.forEach( h -> setNews(news) );` - in other words, giving a the HashTags a reference to their news object which will then fill the news_id column.

Comment: Tried, nothing changed :/

Comment: @zzheads What a mess, the question is not genuine anymore. I have to change the question to the genuine state.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what we have:

On the owning side of the n-m relation:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "news_hashTag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "news_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hashtag_id"))
public Set<HashTag> getHashTags() {
    return hashTags;
}
```

You do not provide the exclusion of `null` values because documentation specifies:

> boolean nullable() default true;

This is wrong for the relationtable as well as the id. You must:

1. Set the ID to `nullable=false`.
2. Set all JoinColumns of the JoinTable to `nullable=false`.

There is another problem: You make a insert and an update by `newsService.save(news);`, you specify a Generator for the ID but have no Generator, this is ok in other databases who provide something like a `nextval` in Oracle. In PostGreSQL you really should use a sequence-field like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "hashtag_id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HashTagIDGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HashTagIDGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_HASHTAG_ID")
```

Have a good time.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for such descriptive answer. Changed everything as suggested, but have same error, for error message see update of my post

Comment: @zzheads Wait, the update in your question is a result of my changes? You added logging-informations, right? If the logging-informations is a result of my suggestions it should not be part of the Question. Add the logging-informations as a comment to my answer please.

Comment: Ok, error message after changes you have suggested: Error message:

WARN 48256 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL
Error: 0, SQLState: 23502 2017-02-12 13:43:24.445 ERROR 48256 ---
[nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR:
null value in column "news_id" violates not-null constraint  
Подробности: Failing row contains (50, null, hashTag_1, null).

Comment: @zzheads Please the complete error message. I wonder about the message, the concrete error shows values of 4 columns but the first insert has 5 columns and the second insert has 3 columns. I think this is a error, could you try to report a bug to hibernate? Have to go now.

Comment: Changed HashTag class - deleted 'description' property.

Comment: Error message I got in JSON response: {
  "timestamp": 1486898183325,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [news_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
  "path": "/api/news"
}

Comment: and Log: Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('seq_news_id')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('seq_hashtag_id')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        news
        (author, date, image, text, news_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        hash_tag
        (name, hashtag_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)

Comment: 2017-02-12 14:16:23.309  WARN 48770 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2017-02-12 14:16:23.309 ERROR 48770 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "news_id" violates not-null constraint
  Подробности: Failing row contains (250, null, hashTag_1, null).